# Check if array contains element less than/more than given value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to check through an array containing only numeric values to ascertain whether ANY of them are below a certain value.

The array is created with below function in jQuery (HTML below):

```js
var $scores = $('.curScore');
var scoresArr = $scores.map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  })
  .get();
```

```html
<h3>Please input your four-skill language test results</h3>
  <label for="curL">Listening: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_L">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="4">4.0</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      <option value="8">8.0</option>
      <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
      <option value="9">9.0</option>
      <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
    </select>
  <label for="curR">Reading: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_R">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="4">4.0</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      <option value="8">8.0</option>
      <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
      <option value="9">9.0</option>
      <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: when I try to run your snippet, it says `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: what is `.get()`? is that a new array method? since that's what your code will try to do

Comment: Would including this in HTML help any?: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: no, because you don't have any code that will run (array does not have a get method) and you don't have any attempt to solve your own problem that has failed in any way ... you just want someone to write the code for you ... so there's really no point in making that into a snippet

Comment: I was advised that using .get() will create an array of the mapped elements (pretty new to this so not 100%!)

Comment: As I say, pretty new to this - looking around for a starting point

Comment: never heard of .get() ... probably a java thing - remove that `.get()` ... and then you can use a simple for loop to check if any of the values in the array meet the criteria you're looking for - scoresArr is an array of strings by the way, you'll need to parseFloat them so they are Numbers

Comment: @jwaterson you only want to check with selected option values or amoung all the option values?

Comment: @Jainil yeah, just the selected values - all I can seem to get ahold of is the inArray() method, (which only lets me know whether a specified value is in the array)

Comment: @jwaterson you can create functions to check the value is greater or less than given value then you can use it with the `$.each` loop.

Comment: @Jainil  this seems to work - any problems with this?: var $scores = $('.curScore'), scoresArr = $scores.map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
   })
 .get();

  $.each(scoresArr, function(index, value){
   parseFloat(value);
   if(value < 6) {
   alert(value);
            }
  })

Comment: (alerting just for the sake of testing)

Comment: Store parseFloat(value) in a variable then do the condition

Comment: @Jainil Thanks again!